# How to concatenate parameters in XPath and return the result

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have two parameters in my XML document that I would like to parse out and concatenate together.

For example, I have have the following two parameters:

```
<param name="param1" type="string">
    <xsl:value-of select="//tr:a/tr:b/c/d/e/f/g/h"/>
</param>        
<param name="param2" type="string">
    <xsl:value-of select="//tr:a/tr:b/c/d/e/f/g/i"/>
</param>
```

How can I concatenate the values of `param1` and `param2` into a single string and display the output?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Where exactly are these "parameters"? And what is the expected result of the concatenation?

Answer (score 0):

In XPath (as per question title), use [**`concat()`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-concat):

```
concat($param1, $param2)
```

In XSLT (per question code example), take the `xsl:value-of` the above XPath:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat($param1, param2)"/>
```

Regarding "and display the output:"  XPath *selects* and has no separate notion of display; XSLT *transforms* but does have `xsl:message` to write to logs.

Comment: You are assuming these parameters are defined in the XSLT stylesheet - but that's not possible, because they are not prefixed with `xsl:`

Comment: You're right, but, yes, I'm assuming it's just an oversight in typing the example.

Comment: It cannot be, because `@type` is not an allowed attribute of `xsl:param`.

Comment: It can be a bigger oversight than you're thinking.  :-)

Comment: Anything is possible, but when it doesn't look like a duck and doesn't walk like a duck ...

Comment: Maybe Bob's [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) knows what Bob is thinking and could clarify for us.